# How to send email to user input email address after click a submit button? In php

Tags: php, html

I'm super new at coding. This is the form page code

```html
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
$fnameErr = $emailErr = $addressErr = $countryErr = $stateErr = $suburbErr = "";
$fname = $email = $address = $country = $state = $suburb = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fnameErr = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }
    
  if (empty($_POST["address"])) {
    $addressErr = "Address is required";
  } else {
    $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["country"])) {
    $countryErr = "City is required";
  } else {
    $country = test_input($_POST["country"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["state"])) {
    $stateErr = "State is required";
  } else {
    $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
  }
  
  if (empty($_POST["suburb"])) {
    $suburbErr = "State is required";
  } else {
    $suburb = test_input($_POST["suburb"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2 align="cemter">Check out</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
  
  Full Name: <input type="name" name="fname">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $fnameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="email" name="email">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Address: <input type="text" name="address">
  <span class="error">*<?php echo $addressErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Country: <input type="text" name="country">
  <span class="error">*<?php echo $countryErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  State: <input type="text" name="state">
  <span class="error">*<?php echo $stateErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Suburb: <input type="text" name="suburb">
  <span class="error">*<?php echo $suburbErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  <form method="post" action="../mailer/index.php">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Purchase"> 
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

But after I fill up all the information and click submit, the page said cannot connect to SMTP sever host. The strange thing is, I can send email while run the phpmailer index.php alone. The form page php file and the mailer php file is in a different folder but same parent folder, is this the problem?

Comment: you cannot send an email but you don't show the code where you send it??

Comment: If one way works and the other doesn't, you need to find out what's different. Are you using the same settings? Maybe you're rewriting some variables in your script, that PHPMailer uses. If you don't include PHPMailer's index.php, are you including proper scripts? Try to comment everything and just run PHPMailer with hardcoded variables in your script. And stuff like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one page works and another doesn't, and these are in different folders, then yes, that could be the problem. However, the solution is probably not to just move one of the files (which would probably give you other path related issues), but instead make sure that they both can reach the neccessary configuration (SMTP server host in this case).

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem. The mailer work fine with XAMPP, but I use MAMP for coding php.